# Analytical Solution for Elastic Bar under applied end velocity

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics

Say, a thin long rod is occupying the space $[0,L]$. It's isotropic, linear elastic, homogeneous. The partial differential equations for stress $\sigma(x,t)$ and displacement $u(x,t)$ are as follows ($E$ denotes the Young's Modulus and $\rho$ the density):

$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} = \frac{1}{\rho} \frac{\partial\sigma}{\partial x}$$
$$ \frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial t} = E \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x\partial t}$$

The bar is initially in rest and free of any stresses. It is fixed to the "left" (at $x = 0$) and a constant velocity is applied to the right. Formally:

$$ \sigma(x,0) = 0$$
$$ u(x,0) = 0$$
$$ u(0,t) = 0$$
$$ \frac{\partial u\left(L,t\right)}{\partial t} = v_{bc}$$

Now my question is simply: Is there an analytical solution for this system? I already tried to find one in Maple, but to now avail.

Comment: Existence of solutions sounds more like a math topic, *unless* you want to know if the setup is physically reasonable enough to admit a solution. I suggest migrating to mathematics, though in that case the users there should take into account that the word "analytical" here probably means "in terms of common functions" rather than simply "converges to its Taylor series."

Comment: Very minor point: for longitudinal waves, like these equations describe, the Young's modulus $E$ should instead be the bulk modulus $K$.

Comment: Migrated to Math.SE because the physics part is taken care of.

Comment: I still think this should not have been migrated. It asks about the solution to a physical problem, and it is more the realm of engineering than math. For me physics = math + units.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equations can be combined for a solution, if initial conditions are known. Strain is $\epsilon = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$, stress $\sigma = E \epsilon$ and the balance of forces yields

$$ \frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial x} = E \frac{\partial \epsilon}{\partial x} = E \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} = \rho \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} $$

and with $c^2=\frac{E}{\rho}$ the wave equation is

$$ \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} = \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} $$

with initial conditions

$$ u(x,0) = 0 $$
  $$ \dot{u}(x,0) = \frac{x}{L} u_{bc} $$ (for smooth velocity function)

The general solution has the form:

$$ u(x,t) = A_0 + B_0 t + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \cos\left(\frac{n \pi x}{L}\right) \left(A_n \sin \left( \frac{n \pi c}{L} t \right) + B_n \left( \frac{n \pi c}{L} t \right) \right) $$
 $$ \dot{u}(x,t) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} u(x,t) $$

with the coefficients $A_n$ and $B_n$ derived from the initial conditions ($u(x,0)$ and $\dot{u}(x,0)$)

$$ A_n = \frac{2}{n \pi c} \int_0^L \cos \left( \frac{n \pi x}{L} \right) \dot{u}(x,0)\,{\rm d} x $$
  $$ B_n = \frac{2}{L} \int_0^L \cos \left( \frac{n \pi x}{L} \right) u(x,0)\,{\rm d} x $$

For your case

$$ A_0 = 0 $$
  $$ B_0 = \frac{1}{2} v_{bc} $$
  $$ B_n = 0 $$
  $$ A_n = \frac{L \left(\cos(\pi n)+\pi n \sin(\pi n)-1\right)}{c \pi^3 n^3} v_{bc} $$

with example output:

[image: Example]

Comment: More information for this technique [here](http://www.math.hmc.edu/~ajb/PCMI/lecture7.pdf0) and [here](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~jmb/lectures/pdelecture2.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for your thorough and helpful answer and references. Would love to upvote it, but I'm missing the reputation.

Comment: So the problem is not the solution, but the initial conditions. Once the initial conditions are transformed in the same terms as the solution series the problem is complete.

Comment: This is not addressing the initial conditions of the original problem. Where are you coming up with $\dot{u}(x,0) = \frac{x}{L} u_{bc}$? The original question has completely different initial conditions

Comment: Essentially I am plucking the rod. I chose continuous & smooth initial conditions along the rod fitting the requirements that $u(L,0)=u_{bc}$ and $u(0,0)=0$.

Comment: That's a different problem. The OP asked for following initial conditions $\sigma(x,0) = 0$ ,$u(x,0) = 0$ and the following boundary conditions :$u(0,t) = 0$ and $\frac{\partial u\left(L,t\right)}{\partial t} = v_{bc}$ . You just picked a different problem to solve?

Comment: You are welcome to add a new answer if you want. From what I understood, I applied constant strain initially. Otherwise, the strain curve has a discontinuity, in the end, making it unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: I'm not claiming to have an answer. I'm claiming that the provided answer does not address the original question. That much I know.

Comment: I think it does because it shows the general _method_ used to solve this problem regardless of the BC. And the OP agrees with me apparently.

Comment: Your method won't work for other boundary conditions, certainly not the OP's. The OP's decision to accept the answer doesn't necessarily make it correct.

Comment: I am curious, why would I be able to find _in theory_ the coefficients $A_n$ and $B_n$ for general BC?